# What is the maximum size of a Ethereum block in geth (kbs,mbs)?

Tags: gas

what is the maximum block size of the Ethereum (need some references ),and can we calculate size with gas if yes please provide any formula,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethereum blocksize is measured in [gas per block](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/).

The maximum size is settable by miners. Currently the maximum block size is 15M gas. It might be different for other networks (Polygon, Binance Smart Chain).

[More information in this post of mine](https://capitalgram.com/posts/scaling-evm/).